# Why does this function give me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to create a linked list which has two elements, `usernames` and `seconds`. It is supposed to read from a file and save it into two vectors.

I'm not sure why, but when I attempt to collect the data and store it into a linked list, I get a segmentation fault.

I'm kind of in a rutt, I feel like this should work.

Here is my code for `main.cpp`:

```cpp
// main.cpp
int main() {
  //Collect initial leaderboard data into two parallel vectors
  cout << "here";
  vector<string> playerNames;
  vector<unsigned> playerTimes;
  collect_data(playerNames, playerTimes);
  cout << "here";
  //Create a LeaderBoard object based on the data in the parallel vectors
  LeaderBoard players(playerNames, playerTimes);
  cout << "Initial leaderboard from https://www.speedrun.com/ac#All_Debts\n";
  players.display();
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
//Leaderboard.cpp
LeaderBoard :: LeaderBoard(const vector<string>& usernames, const vector<unsigned>& second)  //Combines both vectors to linked list;
{
  for (int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++)
  {
    nPlayers_ ++;

    Player *ptr = new Player;
    ptr = nullptr;

    ptr->username = usernames[i];
    ptr->seconds = second[i];

    if (head_ == nullptr)
    {
      head_ = ptr;
      tail_ = ptr;
    }
    else 
    {
      while (tail_-> next != nullptr)
      {
        tail_ = tail_ -> next;
      }
      tail_->next = ptr;
      tail_ = ptr;
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me, or lead me towards the right direction?

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Enable all warnings and debug info when compiling. With GCC, compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part

```
    Player *ptr = new Player;
    ptr = nullptr;

    ptr->username = usernames[i];
    ptr->seconds = second[i];
```

You are overwriting the pointer to newly created object by `nullptr`, then dereferencing the `nullptr`. This will lead to memory leak and Segmentation Fault.

The line

```
    ptr = nullptr;
```

should be removed from here.

Also it seems you forgot to initialize `ptr->next`.

```
    ptr->next = nullptr;
```

should be added after that part.

Comment: Thank you, i made the correction but it still seems that the fault is occuring.

Comment: @Piklez Is `head_` initialized?

Comment: Yes, it has been initialized in the default constuctor to nullptr

Comment: Thank you that helped me alot. I wasnt pointing tail_->next = nullptr, i forgot to insert it into the if statement.

Comment: "*This will lead to ... Segmentation Fault.*" - note that dereferencing a `nullptr` does not guarantee a segfault will occur. It is *undefined behavior*, so anything could happen, including but not limited to a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

This code presents some issues.

First of all, you might ditch heap allocation on each iteration of the for loop, using only once the allocation, before entering the loop. This prevents errors such as:

```
Player *ptr = new Player;
ptr = nullptr;
```

which causes segmentation fault in your code.

Another problem might be that `head_` and `tail_` might also be `nullptr`, so you have to check carefully about both.

You are allocating something on the heap, without caring about deleting the data later.

Why don't you use a std::vectorstd::unique_ptr<Player> to collect all the player scores, so at the end of the program, everything will be deleted?

```
//Assuming there's a vector like this in Leaderboard.h:
#include <memory>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Player>> players_{};

//Leaderboard.cpp
LeaderBoard::LeaderBoard(const vector<string>& usernames, const vector<unsigned>& second)  //Combines both vectors to a final list;
{
  for (int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++)
  {
    Player p{};

    p.username = usernames[i];
    p.seconds = second[i];
    
    players_.emplace_back(std::move(Player));
  }
}
```

In this way, you ditch tricky pointer handling problems, allocation problems, segmentation fault all together. As nice result, you have a vector that can be used with a broad range of algorithms